# How do I get the number of views in the past day on a question?

Tags: support, questions

How do I get the number of **views in the past day** (or within a specific time-range) on a question with the Stack Exchange API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the attribute view_count is not stored each time a view for an unique IP is processed. Instead view_count is a simple counter without history.

If you want to know the number of views for a question over a period of time you have to keep track of the view_count yourself by querying it and storing the result.

The above is also true for [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/). You could determine viewcount for a post per quarter if you download the posts.xml from each [Stack Exchange datadump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).